# AmCharts. XYChart. How to get value in dateAxis tooltip?

Tags: javascript, amcharts

There is a simple demo chart:
https://jsfiddle.net/atp5ejdb/1/

There are default tooltips for date and value axis.
Tooltip for bullets could contain the value and date, but I can't show value in `dateAxis` tooltip in any way. I need somehow to get it in `dateAxis` as easy as to get from usual series tooltip.

I have tried to play with adapters but seems to me they are only related to default dates and values separately.

I don't need tooltips for `valueAxis` and can disable it, but how to get values within html/text `dateAxis` tooltip?

I need smth like this within `dateAxis` tooltip:

```
<div>{value}</div>
<div>{date}</div>
```